# Using jquery's on in place of live - how can I get the filtered elements

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I am replacing my old .live() event bindings with .on(), like this:

```
$(document).on(event, selector, function () {
    console.log($(this)); //$(this) refers to the $(document) element, not the selector

});
```

What I want to do is get access to the element that this event is being applied to. Any ideas?

This works:

```
$(selector).on(event, function () {
    console.log($(this)); //$(this) refers to the selector
});
```

But it doesn't work the same way as live - new elements added to the document that match the selector won't be bound...

Thanks!

Comment: you are wrong . $(this)  - is the element. not document. http://jsbin.com/uqiwar/edit#javascript,html

Comment: that is quite possible. i'll try again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, your assumption is incorrect:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
  alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Of this, we are told "Display each paragraph's text in an alert box whenever it is clicked." As such, the `this` reference is to the element matched by the filtering selector.

You could test this yourself by setting up an example to alert the `nodeName` of the `this` object:

```
$("body").on("click", "p", function(){
  alert( this.nodeName ); // p
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/eseduf/edit#javascript,html

I noticed you are using a variable as your filtering selector - make sure you have a value set for this variable. If you don't, you will find that the main selector will capture the event, and not the filtering selector:

```
var selector;
$("body").on("click", selector, function(){
  alert( this.nodeName ); // body
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "selector" that the event will apply to.  Do something like live, do this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() { console.log($(this)); });
```

Better would be to emulate .delegate, and narrow the scope to the containing element:

```
$("#containingElement").on("click", "a", function() { console.log($(this)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jsFiddle...  http://jsfiddle.net/nc9XD/1/

The "on" method will pick up new elements... as long as they are added to the element which you bound the on event to to.

Also.. "this" will refer to the element that was clicked inside your function.